# Assign single dimension array as an element of two(multi) dimensional array in (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

Please apologize for my English first.
Let us typedef single and two(multi) dimensional arrays respectively as below:

```
typedef float VERTREX[3];
typedef VERTREX TRIANGLE[3];
```

then say I have initialized some VERTEX arrays,

```
VERTREX v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
VERTREX v2 = { 2, 2, 3 };
VERTREX v3 = { 1, 2, 1 };
```

Assume mathematically a Triangle defined by combination of three vertices,therefore I defined a Triangle as following code snippet,

```
TRIANGLE tr;
```

Problem arisen when I am going to assign each **VERTEX**(single dimension array) elements in to **TRIANGLE**(Array of arrays/2-Dimensional array) as below code,

```
tr[0] = v1; // error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value(in Visual C++ compiler)
tr[1] = v2; //  error C2106:
tr[2] = v3; //  error C2106:
```

Also I cannot continue with creating array of Triangles too.

```
TRIANGLE tr[4]; // creating array of Triangles
```

hence same behavior can be expected.
If someone has an idea/solution how to assign Single Dimension array as an element of Two(Multi) Dimensional array please respond.Please do not provide solution with standard containers like std::vector or using raw pointers approach.
**Please bound to array concept.**
Thank you everyone for listening.
Please provide clean answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you really need to use typedefs:

```
typedef float VERTREX[];
typedef float* TRIANGLE[3];

int main() {

  VERTREX v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
  VERTREX v2 = { 2, 2, 3 };
  VERTREX v3 = { 1, 2, 1 };

  TRIANGLE tr;

  tr[0] = v1;
  tr[1] = v2;
  tr[2] = v3;

  TRIANGLE triangle[4];
  return 0;
}
```

But I would highly recommend using the std::array approach. It is less prone to errors and misuse. Users won't know that VERTREX or TRIANGLE are arrays.

Comment: We post answer at same time instance :D thanx for the reply

Comment: why did you remain/define VERTEX array as un-sized ? any Compiler side reasoning?

Comment: No reason. You can add the array size if you want.

Comment: @llias can you compare/differ your answer with my answer ? any identified critical issue?

Comment: I don't think you need to assign the pointers to the arrays in the triangle. This makes things more complicated when using it.

Comment: @llias -> Agreed.Thanx for the info' friend and for you concern and time.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef`s are aliases. They don't define new types.

```
TRIANGLE tr;
tr[0] = v1;
```

is similar to:

```
VERTEX temp;
temp = v1;
```

If you remove `typedef` and use the actual types, that is equivalent to:

```
float v1[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
float temp[3];
temp = v1;
```

That is not allowed in C/C++. You cannot assign to an array like that.

You'll need to copy the elements one by one, or use `memcpy`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   tr[0][i] = v1[i];
```

or

```
memcpy(tr[0], v1, sizeof(v1));
```

When you use an array of `TRIANGLE`s, you'll have to use a similar strategy to copy a `TRIANGLE` to an element of the array.

---

Since these sizes are defined at compile time, I strongly suggest use of `std::array`.

Here's a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using VERTEX = std::array<float, 3>;
using TRIANGLE = std::array<VERTEX, 3>;

int main()
{
   VERTEX v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
   VERTEX v2 = { 2, 2, 3 };
   VERTEX v3 = { 1, 2, 1 };

   TRIANGLE tr;
   tr[0] = v1;

   TRIANGLE trArray[4];
   trArray[0] = tr;

   std::cout << v1[0] << " " << v1[1] << " " << v1[2] << std::endl;
}
```

and here's the output:

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sahu :),but Can't we find an answer  if we define TRIANGLE data type as typedef VERTREX (*TRIANGLE)[3] ?

Comment: @Dinithi, that won't make use of `VERTEX` and `TRIANGLE` any more intuitive. I think your best option is to use `std::array`.

Comment: accept that thanx for the suggestion,my doubt was that ,std::array/std::vector has performance issue regarding accessing/writing elements in to containers with respect to raw array.Is that faulty idea?

Comment: `std::array` should be as speedy as regular arrays. `std::vector` should be good for most use cases too.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding,please correct me on this,
Assume we has vector of Big-Data ,say we have to insert huge number of elements in to the vector,as I know *push_back* operation will be a caused to latency/performance hit for a particular program

Comment: Isn't that calling *push_back* operation many number of times on Big-Data/Objects caused performance degradation?

Comment: @Dinithi, The number of allocations can be reduced by using [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112462/discussion-between-dinithi-and-r-sahu).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef float VERTREX[3];
typedef VERTREX* TRIANGLE[3];

int main()
{
    VERTREX v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    VERTREX v2 = { 11, 21, 13 };
    VERTREX v3 = { 1, 12, 41 };


    TRIANGLE tr;
    tr[0] = &v1;
    tr[1] = &v2;
    tr[2] = &v3;
    tr[3] = &v3;  --(1)// Concept(Array size) violation - Expect Runtime error 

    std::cout << (*(&v3))[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*tr[2])[2] << std::endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

// Compile with Visual C++(v.120) with Warning Level 4 ,No warning if we eliminate the line (1), here output:
41
41

Comment: If you have any optimization or conceptual suggestion please response

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct but I will try simplify explanation of that error. Even if it looks complicated it is quite simple:

Whole error is caused just because you can't assign to array:

```
int array[5];
int another_array[5];
array = another_array; //error, can't assign to array
```

Now, let's try it with multidimensional array:

```
int array_of_array[5][2];
int regular_array[2];
array_of_array[0] = regular_array; // error can't assign to array
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer,your point is correct,we have also noticed that,but what we wanted a generalized solution for the purpose.